# Trouble with Internet Explorer pop-ups and closing windows

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

So for this project I am facing a little bit of a problem.

Overview: I send my clients a link to a webpage.  On that webpage I need to display information(First Name, Last Name, dob etc) to my user in a convenient fashion which will be copied and pasted into a third party page.  I originally wanted to use iFrame and display the information and third party site all on one page but the third party has iFrame blocked.  My next solution was to make 2 popup windows that launch on-load of the webpage, One a thin horizontal on the top of the screen with the information needed, the second filling the rest of the page with the third party site. The next feature I need is too close the 3 pages(landing page, information window, and third party site) easily when one of the child windows is closed.

I have gotten just about exactly what I want to work in Chrome but the problem is I need to to work in Internet Explorer.  In Chrome, the webpage automatically launches the two pop-up windows, and when either is closed all three windows shut down.  In IE the two webpages pop-up but then they automatically exit and close in a couple of seconds.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<button onclick="closeWin()"> Close</button> 
<body onload="infoPopup()">
</body>

<script>
var myWindow;
var myWindowB;
function infoPopup(){

        var windowDimensions = ("scrollbars=1,width="+(screen.width-10)+",height=150");
        myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", windowDimensions);
        myWindow.moveTo(0,0);
        myWindow.location="https://google.com"

        var myWindowBDimensions = ("scrollbars=1,width="+(screen.width-10)+",height="+(screen.height-250));
        myWindowB = window.open("", "myWindowB", myWindowBDimensions);
        myWindowB.moveBy(0,150);
        myWindowB.location="https://wikipedia.org";

        var timer = setInterval(checkChild, 500);

        function checkChild() {
            if (myWindow.closed||myWindowB.closed) {
                closeWin();   
                clearInterval(timer);
            }
        }
}
        function closeWin(){
            myWindow.close();
            myWindowB.close();
            window.close();
        }
</script>
</html>
```

I'm assuming the problem lies with the

```
if (myWindow.closed||myWindowB.closed)
```

Maybe IE is not properly reading these conditions?

I know that pop-ups are often frowned upon and controlling webpages should be left up to the user, but for this project this is only a smaller piece of a process and needs to be completed and closed quickly.  Any help or suggestions for other alternatives are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a known bug in Internet Explorer 9, per [this bug report](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/241109).

You might be able to figure something tricky out using window.onunload() or window.unbeforeunload(), similar to Microsoft's workaround of keeping a boolean in the parent window, then onunload(), set the bool to false.

```
var childLoaded = true;

myWindowB.addEventListener("unload", function(){childLoaded=false;});
```